# Unalignable boolean Series key provided ( of the type df [ df [ df )

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a df and a condition df[df['EmployeeName'] == 'JOSEPH DRISCOLL'] gives the following output[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXcmT.png)

And when I enter this df[df['EmployeeName'] == 'JOSEPH DRISCOLL']['BasePay'] > 140000
it gives an output like this

24    True

Name: BasePay, dtype: bool

Now Can't I do something like this

df[df[df['EmployeeName'] == 'JOSEPH DRISCOLL']['BasePay'] > 140000 ]

And expect the same output as the Image above??

Answer (score 0):

You need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) or [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) with boolean mask created by `|` (`or`), `&` (`and`) or `~` (`not`):

```
df1 = df[(df['EmployeeName'] == 'JOSEPH DRISCOLL') & (df['BasePay'] > 140000)]
```

Or:

```
df1 = df.query("EmployeeName == 'JOSEPH DRISCOLL' & BasePay > 140000")
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'EmployeeName':['JOSEPH DRISCOLL','q'],'BasePay':[1000000,10]})
print (df)
   BasePay     EmployeeName
0  1000000  JOSEPH DRISCOLL
1       10                q

print ((df['EmployeeName'] == 'JOSEPH DRISCOLL') & (df['BasePay'] > 140000))
0     True
1    False
dtype: bool

df1 = df[(df['EmployeeName'] == 'JOSEPH DRISCOLL') & (df['BasePay'] > 140000)]
print (df1)
   BasePay     EmployeeName
0  1000000  JOSEPH DRISCOLL

df1 = df.query("EmployeeName == 'JOSEPH DRISCOLL' & BasePay > 140000")
print (df1)
   BasePay     EmployeeName
0  1000000  JOSEPH DRISCOLL
```

Comment: Yep. I can do with &. I am not trying to solve a particular query here but rather understand what is wrong with my understanding that I believe df [df [df [  should work